# Can not set selected value in select tag using angular.js and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have one issue regarding select tag in angular.js.I am binding data in select tag dynamically which are coming from Database.Here i am unable to set selected default text in select tag.I am explaining my code below.

> role.html:

```
<select id="coy" name="coy" class="form-control" ng-model="user_name"  ng-options="user.name for user in listOfName track by user.value" >
 </select>
```

My controller code for set the value inside select tag is given below.

```
$scope.listOfName=[];
$scope.listOfName=[{
        name: 'User Name',
        value: ''
    }]
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "php/userrole/getUserData.php",
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }).then(function successCallback(response){
        angular.forEach(response.data,function(obj1){
            var user={'name':obj1.user_name,'value':obj1.user_name};
            $scope.listOfName.push(user);
        });
    },function errorCallback(response) {

    });
```

Here i am able to fetch all data and bind them inside select tag but here i am not able to show the `User Name` as default selected text means no default selected text is coming after data bind.Please help me.

Comment: why are you using content type as application/x-www-form-urlencoded ? what's the format of data you are receiving? what's the returned value of php/userrole/getUserData.php?

Comment: i am receiving the data like this `{data: Array[3], status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"} ` way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
angular.forEach(response.data, function(obj1) {
    var user = {
        'name': obj1.user_name,
        'value': obj1.user_name
    };
    $scope.listOfName.push(user);
});
$scope.user_name = $scope.listOfName[0];
```

Comment: No,there is no solution.

Comment: is $scope.user_name a truly object reference from $scope.listOfName ? please debug it.